# Loading a jqgrid table using jsonstring datatype

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I would like to load a jqGrid table with a json String I produce from velocity; these are the table parameters:

```
var gridParams = {
    datatype: "jsonstring", 
    data: content,
    pager: $('#pagernav'), 
    rowNum: 5000,
    rownumbers: true,
    rowList: [50,100,200,500,1000,2000],
    ignoreCase: true,
    colNames: columns,
    colModel: tableColModel,
}
```

The values of content and columns, when printed on the console are:

```
[{"ID":"7", "fname":"Bob", "addr":"18" }, {"ID":"8", "fname":"Sue" }]
["ID", "fname", "addr"]
```

Indeed the grid is created with the right columns, but it is empty...what is wrong with what I wrote? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It might be the missing `addr` in the second element in your data array.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't change anything...

Comment: found another possibility: try using `datastr:` instead of `data:`.

Comment: The pager is shown better now, but no signs of content...

Comment: Okay, then I'm out of guesses. Let's hope someone else can help you some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all more as 90% of usage of `datatype: "jsonstring"` is in case of usage jqGrid in wrong way. You don't describe your original problem more detailed, but I recommend you to consider to use `datatype: "json"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`.

If you do really need to use `datatype: "jsonstring"` then you should provide input data using `datastr` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) instead of `data` option used in case of `datatype: "local"`.

Are the data from `content` are really JSON string (`typeof content === "string"`) or you have the data as the object (`typeof content === "string"`)? It seems to me that it's better to use in your case `datatype: "local", data: content` or `datatype: "local", data: $.parseJSON(content)` instead of usage `datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: content,` because the format of the input data is not standard required for `datatype: "jsonstring"` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_string)) so to be able to read the data successfully you will have to provide the corresponding `jsonReader` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function) an example)

In any way I would recommend you to use `gridview: true` option, replace `pager: $('#pagernav')` to `pager: '#pagernav'` and to define `key: true` property for `'ID'` column. Moreover you should alway include `colModel` in the text of the question. The text of `colModel: tableColModel` goes in the direction to the code `$.jqGrid(myOptions)` - if shows no required detailed which can be very important for finding solution of *your problem*.

Comment: @user1012480: You are welcome! I recommend you really to post more full code which you use and more full description of the problem. For example you post `gridParams`. Typical error is calling of `$("#gridid").jqGrid(gridParams);` more as **once**. The call create many *outer dives* over `<table id="gridid"></table>`, so one should create it once only. The fact of definition of `gridParams` as object could mean that you try to call it more as once without destroying. All next calls will be just ignored by jqGrid abd you can have unclear behavior of the grid.